# Flutter data to convert to double

Tags: flutter, dart

I have simple data I need to convert into a double. Sometimes it's already double and sometimes it's coming in integer.

I am doing like this

```
if (data['status'].toString() == "success") {
  all_rating = double.tryParse(data['over_all_rating']);
  speed_rating = double.tryParse(data['over_speed_rating']);
  break_rating = double.tryParse(data['harsh_braking_rating']);
  concering_rating = double.tryParse(data['harsh_conering_rating']);
  acceleration_rating = double.tryParse(data['harsh_accleration_rating']);
}
```

data look like this

```
{status: success, over_all_rating: 3.25, over_speed_rating: 3.15, harsh_braking_rating: 4.95, harsh_conering_rating: 5, harsh_accleration_rating: 4.95}
```

But don't know why it showing an error of `Unhandled Exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

I am trying to convert in by double.parse so if value is not double it will convert.

Comment: The data in JSON are already `double` and `int`, no need to parse it. Just use `as double;` or `(... as num).toDouble();`.

Answer (score 0):

use it like this:
all_rating = double.tryParse(data['over_all_rating'].toString());